# Cassandra change data storage

Tags: cassandra

Currently I'm using one disk for saving data of Cassandra. I want to switch to new disk (remove current) and keep the current data.

Do you have any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just copy over the files (when the node is not running). Often your data is somewhere like `/var/lib/cassandra/data`.

- shut down the node
- copy all data to the new disk
- mount new disk to the correct location
- restart the node

That should be it.

Comment: To elaborate you set the data directory with the "data_file_directories" value in cassandra.yaml

Comment: @Mandraenke I will give you thumb up, but I was aware that I will need to do something like this but with this suggestion your node can be for hours in downtime, and after 3 hourse it will stop trying to even write on that node. 
This is maybe better approach: http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/02/25/removing-a-disk-mapping-from-cassandra.html